# How do I mutate the input using gradient descent in PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm new to PyTorch. I learned it uses `autograd` to automatically calculate the gradients for the gradient descent function.

Instead of adjusting the weights, I would like to mutate the input to achieve a desired output, using gradient descent. So, instead of the weights of neurons changing, I want to keep all of the weights the same and just change the input to minimize the loss.

For example. The network is a trained image classifier with the numbers 0-9. I input random noise, and I want to morph it so that the network considers it a `3` with 60% confidence. I would like to utilize gradient descent to adjust the values of the input (originally noise) until the network considers the input to be a `3`, with 60% confidence.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: That is not possible with just one network. You will need something like GAN (Generative adversarial network), which is a combination of 2 networks, to make this work.

Comment: Yes, you can. Take a look at this [official tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/neural_style_tutorial.html#gradient-descent).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you know how to do regular training with gradient descent. You only need to change the parameters to be optimized by the optimizer. Something like

```py
# ... Setup your network, load the input
# ...

# Set proper requires_grad -> We train the input, not the parameters
input.requires_grad = True
for p in network.parameters():
    p.requires_grad = False

# Setup the optimizer
# Previously we should have SomeOptimizer(net.parameters())
optim = SomeOptimizer([input])

output_that_you_want = ...
actual_output = net(input)
some_loss = SomeLossFunction(output_that_you_want, actual_output)
# ...
# Back-prop and optim.step() as usual
```

Comment: What if we are using a dataloader? It will be a bit complicated cause idk if we have to add the inputs to the optimizer inside the training loop or before that?